# Kendo CurrencyTextBox displays 200.00 as 20000

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI to create an input box,
I want to automatically display the amount user have to pay in the textbox before,
so that user will only have to insert an amount if it differs from default
The data is given as decimal number.

I have tried:

```
@(Html.Kendo().CurrencyTextBoxFor(model => model.Paid).Format("R#0.00").Min(0))
```

And now also:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor<decimal>(model => model.Paid).Format("R#.##").Min(0))
```

for some reason the textbox just keeps displaying two extra zeros

Comment: Does it act as same in normal textbox? I mean other than kendo textbox? Are you using asp.net core? Do you hav any perticular culture other than English?

Comment: It does not act the same in a normal textbox, It displays with the separation still in place. We are still using ,net framework 4.8, and kendo 2021. As far as I know we do not have any cultures install.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Then this solution might not work.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me, In web.config I added

<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US"/>
</system.web>

which seems to work.

If you add that to your answer for .net framework users who still have to upgrade to core, i can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason the textbox just keeps displaying two extra zeros

Yes, as per my investigation upon your code snippet it might be because of your `default-culture`. However, we can customize it as per the requirement. You could follow below steps:

**Program.cs:**

```
var defaultCulture = "en-US";
var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultCulture);
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."; // Defining my preferrence for number
ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

// Configuring Number Seperator Using Localization middleware
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    }
});
```

**Note:** As you can see in `NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` I am setting my preferrence for seperator. You are open to use anything you want, any kind of charaters. Please consider the order as well while placing the code in middleware. Best use would be end of your `current middleware`. As following:

[image]

**Update for Classic Asp.net 4.8 and Older:**

We can configure above steps for `asp.net classic` project as well. To set the UI culture and culture for all pages, [add a globalization section to the Web.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bz9tc508(v=vs.100)#to-set-the-culture-and-ui-culture-for-an-aspnet-web-page-declaratively), and then set the uiculture and culture attributes, as shown in the following example:

```
<system.web>  
  <globalization   
    culture="en-US"/>  
</system.web>
```

**Note:** [More details can be found here in official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.globalizationsection?view=netframework-4.8)

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** For further reference you could check our official document below.

1. [`Custom numeric format strings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)
2. [`The "." custom specifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-1)